# How to produce screenshot animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Somebody please suggest me the best package or any way to provide a screenshot taken effect in flutter. Please don't downvote.If I did anything wrong

Comment: search on pub dev

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

Comment: what does "taking screenshots" have to do with animations? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: when I press the screenshot widget, Screen needs to animation effect. (just providing UI effect that the screenshot have been taken)

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what animation you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve the effect you are looking for is having your page in a `Stack`. One entry of the `Stack` will be your `Scaffold` page, and the other one will be a white `Container` that fills the screen space. Something like this in your page's build method:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Stack(
    children: [
        Container(color: Colors.white),
        Scaffold(
            // The rest of your page
        ),
    ],
);
```

Then, you can wrap your white `Container` in an `AnimatedOpacity` widget (check out [this Flutter.dev article on how to animate fading widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation)), and define an animation such that the white `Container` fades in and then fades out very quickly, achieving a flash-like effect. In the article I mentioned they also explain how to trigger such an animation programatically.

Comment: That worked for me, only that I needed to use `StackWithAllChildrenReceiveEvents` which can be found over https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-575447316.